# rails submit additional parameters of check boxes to create action

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model, rails-activerecord

I created a new rails project and generated some scaffolds.

For this question I will talk about two models/entities/classes:

```
Model_A
Model_B
```

I'm talking about a fresh setup of the rails project and automatically generated code when using scaffold.

The relationship between `Model_A` and `Model_B` is: `Model_A` has many `Model_B`s and `Model_B` belongs to `Model_A`

I want to edit the New-Form in `new.html.erb` of `Model_A`. When calling `/Model_As` in a browser it shows me the form. I updated the form so it shows me a list of every `Model_B` Object I created before. Every line contains a `check_box` and here is my problem:

When I call `/Model_As` I want to create a new object of `Model_A`. `Model_A` has many `Model_B` so it would be nice to check some listed `Model_B` Objects and when I press submit the `Model_A` Object will be created with references to the checked `Model_B` Objects. Doesn't sound that tricky but I can't solve it.

How do I have to modify the `Model_A` controller? Do I have to add a route? And how does my form-code has to look like?

I know about the `form_helper` for `check_box_tag` but no luck yet.

Ether I do get the necessary `params` (an array of the ids of the check object) but the `Model_A` object is not getting created. Or the object is getting creating but the ids are not submitted.

I think this is no problem for experienced ruby/rails developers. I am new to this stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: It really helps when you show source code. It's a lot harder to imagine what you're doing than it is read a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make changes in two file mainly.

1. `controllers/model_as_controller.rb` - the `new` action

   ```
   def new
     @model_a = Model_A.new
     @model_bs = Model_B.all
   end
   ```
2. `views/model_as/new.html.erb` - In the form for a new @model_a

   ```
   <%= form_for ... %>
     ...

     <%= hidden_field_tag :model_bs %>
     <% @model_bs.each do |model_b| %>
       <%= check_box_tag "model_bs[]", model_b.id %>
       <%= label_tag("model_b_#{model_b.id}", model_b.name) %>
     <% end %>

     ...
   <% end %>
   ```
3. `controllers/model_as_controller.rb` - the `create` action.
   After the form on `new.html.erb` is submitted the application is routed to this create action.
   The list of checked model_bs will come as a string of ids of Model_B objects separated by commas.
   The format will be - "1,4,7". So you write the following code to extract them into an array of ids

   ```
   def create
     model_bs = Model_B.find(params[:model_bs])

     ... # the code to create the @model_a object and save it
     ...

     @model_a.model_bs << model_bs # This will set the model_a id in all the model_b objects
     @model_a.save!

     ... #code to redirect on success or render 'new' on failure
   end
   ```

Make sure that there is a field `model_a_id` in the Model_bs table and the `has_many :model_bs` and `belongs_to :model_a` lines written in appropriate models.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for answering, but it doesn't work. The Model_A is getting created and forwarding works fine, but when I want to see the result its empty. I modified the show.html.erb of Model_A to list all @model_a.exercises but its empty.

Is there no way to do this without JavaScript? No Ruby/Rails way?

Comment: Try the edited code. I removed all the javascript from the view.

Comment: Now I'm getting "expected Array (got String) for param `model_bs'" on submitting the form (Internal Server Error).

Comment: Sorry, I compared my code with yours again carefully and found some mistakes in my code. Now everything works like I wanted it to. Thank you very much!